# Firebase: displayName is null after signing up and updating profile

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a ReactJS app with Firebase as my backend and I'm facing some difficulties.

`displayName` is null after running `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `updateProfile`, it is however populated after I refresh the page but I need to access it without reloading the page.

Also swapping `onAuthStateChanged` to `onIdTokenChanged` seems to work, I have `displayName` populated right after `updateProfile` is executed but is this right? I haven't seen tutorials with this.

This is what I have

```js
// AuthProvider.js

const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

function signup(email, password) {
  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}

function updateDisplayName(name) {
  return updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { displayName: name });
}

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user)
      setCurrentUser({
        uid: user.uid,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      });
    else setCurrentUser(null);

    setLoading(false);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

and

```js
// SignUpModal.js

const onSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
  try {
    await signup(values.email, values.password);
    await updateDisplayName(values.username);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Should I manually update `currentUser` after `updateProfile` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged), you'll read that the observer only runs when the user signs in or signs out. Since your user remains signed in after changing his name, the observer will not run again.

As suggested by the documentation, I would change `onAuthStateChanged` to `onIdTokenChanged`

Comment: Thank you, I was curious about good code practices.